# Output encoding in ASPNET webform

Tags: encoding, xss

I'd like to understand the contextual encoding technique in XSS mitigation, so that I can look at for example a URL and decide if the encoding should be URL only or maybe URL and also HTML. I want to learn to detect what output contextual encoding is the right against XSS attack in ASPNET webforms. With examples would be ideal.

Comment: You're asking about "HTML encoding", but asking for an external resource is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Rephrased the original statement so that no external resource is asked for.